# can't find the android device in target android device's list

Tags: android

I have installed usb driver, selected the android device's debugging mode but i can't access the android device in the target android device's list.I am using htc wildfire as my android device. i chose the connection type of my device to my pc as Disk Drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to choose loading only for a debugging and testing connection.

Comment: janusz, will u please explain it.. i am new to android

Comment: On my device at the moment I plug it via USB to my computer a dialog pops up that enables me tho choose the connection type. There should be something like loading/charging only in the dialog. If there is no dialog you may be able to open it via the notificaiton bar on the top of your screen.

Comment: there are 3 options on my device,charge only,HTC sync and Disk drive. should i choose HTC sync??